# How to set array and asserts in SonataAdmin with a MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I have a project with symfony2, sonataAdmin and MongoDB.

I have a variable that I am using with collection type to map to MongoDB.

But I want to use in two different forms. In one form it will be accepted multiple choices. In the other only one choice will be permitted. (in both we must choose one).

The problem is that if I choose collection as type, in the admin it doesn't work with the checkbox. That means the page gives a 500 error.

If I use string as type, in the admin it doesn't work with the radiobutton (the value that I clicked disappears once i submit the form).

There is any solution for this problem? Other MongoDB type? I can't find any easy solution.

Comment: I didn't get the "it doesn't work with" part. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @greg0ire, when I use a string as type, the form return a 500 error when I try to set "multiple" to true (it makes sense, I am trying to put an array in a string)

when I use collection as type, the form doesn't stay with the data submitted when "multiple" is false (radiobutton).